# QGIS: is there a way to specify labels for only some countries?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS,I want to display only the names of counties which have data of more than 1 (the data range is 1-18), and not display all country names on a world map.

I'm on a Mac.

I don't think 'priority' will work on its own, and it might need a string?

In the attributes, I have a column with no. projects (so 1-18 for <15 countries), and wondered if this could be part of the string. Something like 'if more than 1, label with country name'.

Comment: This does not seem to be a coding question, and thus not appropriate for this site. You should have more response on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: you can use a `rule` to set which labels to show